# Highcharts getSVG plotOptions series.lineWidth not working

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I am attempting to set some plotOptions (mainly lineWidth) on a highchart's getSVG call, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work.

The code below is able to set the exported SVG file's width and height properly, but getSVG seems to ignore the rest of what I've written.

My chart has two series, and I would like to thicken the lineWidth for both series. Highcharts documentation says I should be able to adjust the lineWidth when I call getSVG, but doesn't actually show an example where they pull this off.

I have a feeling I'm not formatting this correctly or something. Any thoughts?

My code :

```
var chart = $('#patient-chart').highcharts();

var svg = chart.getSVG({
  chart: {
    width: 1200,
    height: 660
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      lineWidth: 10
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: where you are trying to invoke chart.getSVG? you may call it on any external function/click

Comment: Robert - The documentation does not provide a working example inside the context of getSVG.

Comment: Nishith - wiring this up to a button click isn't going to make any difference and is not needed in my case. I just need to SVG to get spat out as the chart is being rendered. Other programming further down the line grabs the SVG data and stores it to a network location.

Answer (score 1):

Pawelfus on Github figured out a workaround here by hooking into the chart load event: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4583#issuecomment-141441315

My code:

```
        var chart = $('#patient-chart').highcharts();
        var svg = chart.getSVG({
            chart: {
                width: 1200,
                height: 660,
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        this.series[0].update({
                            lineWidth: 5
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug, because lineWidth is ignored also in chartOptions.

Reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4583

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know, Sebastian.